# ExtJs: TreeLoader: it doesn't work but why?

Tags: javascript, extjs

If I do this : it works :

```
var myTreeLoader = new Ext.tree.TreeLoader({
        dataUrl: 'json/test.php',
});
```

If I add this code it doesn't work :

```
var myTreeLoader = new Ext.tree.TreeLoader({
        dataUrl: 'json/test.php',
        load : function(loader,node,response) { }
 });
```

My question is : why ?
Edit/Delete Message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer was:

```
var MyTreeLoader = new Ext.tree.TreeLoader({
    dataUrl: 'json/lys.php',
    listeners: {
        load: function(loader,node,response) {
            console.log('datas loaded');
        }
    }
});
```

Mr bmoeskau was right. I was overriding a function instead of add a listener.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more specific -- I did not realize you were trying to handle the load event.  Glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you are overriding the built-in `load()` method with an empty implementation.  What were you expecting it to do if it can't load data?

Comment: See http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.tree.TreeLoader

( => Public Methods : load(...) :Load an Ext.tree.TreeNode from the URL specified in the constructor ==> Public Events : load: (...) Fires when the node has been successfuly loaded.) 

Two different things for the same object... maybe you're right maybe ... not.

Answer (score 1):

Some browers (e.g. IE) won't like the trailing comma after dataUrl.  Not sure if that is your problem here, but it's a never ending source of many JS problems.

Comment: This wasn't the real problem but I'll keep your advice in mind, thanks.